# How to get list using sql query in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg

I am defining a function here and making a query.

```
def fetch(temp_pass,temp_accno):
    cur.execute('''SELECT id, name, acc_no, ph_no,address, email,balance
               FROM accounts
               WHERE id = %s and acc_no = %s''',
            (str(temp_pass), str(temp_accno)));
    row = cur.fetchall()
    print(row[2])
```

In this row should be a list of length 7 but when I run **print(row[2])**
it gives me error that list index out of range.

**This is the error I get**

```
File "Accounting.py", line 13, in fetch
    print(row[2])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: For debugging purposes, you can try to print the contents of the `row` to make sure that the list actually has 7 elements. From the error, it seems that it doesn't.

Comment: @TudorPlugaru it only has one element I dont know why

Comment: Because the query only returns one row.

Comment: You filter by id. Usually id is unique field. You can do row[0][2] to get 3 field of single row that was been returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`row = cur.fetchall()` won't give you a row but a list of rows, so `row` is not a row at all and `row[2]` is the third row in the list, not the third field in a row. If you want only a row use `cur.fetchone()`.

Note the the query might return several rows and it is not clear what you want to do in that case so I won't deal with it here. `cur.fetchone()` will give you only one row anyway.

Comment: Okay now I get it, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`row[2]` returns the 3rd row of the list of rows.  `row[0][2]` returns the 3rd column of the 1st row.

You could run a snippet like this to visualize what gets returned:

```
cur.execute(...)
for row in cur:
    print(row)
```

Comment: row[0][2] works great. Thanks but I still don't understand why row[2] didn't work